# Rails 7: I want to put code in /lib/ instead of writing a gem, but I'm getting NoMethodError

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I added some code to the `/lib/` directory in my rails app, which was not even recognised by rails probably due to loading, so I moved it to `/app/lib/` then it was at least recognised, but not I get a NoMethodError when calling a method inside a module. Here is some of the code I placed in `app/lib`

```
# frozen_string_literal: true

module Github
  module Auth

    def connection
      Faraday.new(
        url: 'https://github.com'
      )
    end

    def authorize
      connection.get(
        '/login/oauth/authorize',
        params: {
          client_id: '<My client id here>',
          redirect_uri: '<My callback here>'
        }
      )
    end

  end
end
```

I then have an `AuthorizeController` class, from which I want to call this code;

```
class AuthorizeController < ApplicationController

  def index
    response = Github::Auth.authorize
    redirect_to response[:location] , allow_other_host: true
  end

end
```

For which I get the following error:

[image]

Like I said, I moved the code from `/lib/` to `/app/lib/` which made Rails at least recognise the code, but this feels hacky to me and probably isn't the best way to do this. I also don't want to write an entire gem just for this functionality

I previously had this code inside the controller, but I want it to be in lib. What is the best practice to achieve this?

Thank you from a Rails noob! :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error has nothing to do with the file location - rather if you want to define a "module method" you need to define it with `self`:

```ruby
module Github
  module Auth
    def self.connection
      Faraday.new(
        url: 'https://github.com'
      )
    end

    def self.authorize
      connection.get(
        '/login/oauth/authorize',
        params: {
          client_id: '<My client id here>',
          redirect_uri: '<My callback here>'
        }
      )
    end
  end
end
```

Instance methods of a module are only available within encapsulating objects - for example an instance of a class that includes the module.

You can also provide access to instance methods of a module from the singleton with the oddly named [`Module#module_function`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/Module.html#method-i-module_function) method:

```ruby
module Github
  module Auth
    def connection
      Faraday.new(
        url: 'https://github.com'
      )
    end

    def authorize
      connection.get(
        '/login/oauth/authorize',
        params: {
          client_id: '<My client id here>',
          redirect_uri: '<My callback here>'
        }
      )
    end
    module_function :connection, :authorize
  end
end
```

Comment: There is also the option of using `extend self` in the module to make the methods callable similar to `module_function`. And I think the OP's issue with the module not found when defined in `lib` is probably due to it not being auto-loaded.